# How to change the guest session keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout, guest-session

I use the Dvorak keyboard layout. When I switch to a guest session it defaults to the Dvorak layout as well. Unfortunately this only produces gibberish for most people typing.

Is there a way to set the default guest session keyboard layout?

Answer (score 0):

Actually as far as I know , You can't do that , You can have 2 user accounts and each one with a different keyboard style , But a Guest doesn't get those settings and a user can't change then , Most likely you can do it in the Terminal with UNIX commands or GRUB but I am not a expert with that , Sorry I can not help that much but the easiest way is making a a Guest User Account on it and limiting the things it can do , Not making it an admin , And putting a password only you can know

Comment: Actually you can do that. I just showed how in an answer to a similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/413953/guest-session-fails-when-using-prefs-sh