# How can I set keyboard layout for the guest session?

Tags: keyboard-layout, guest-session

First, my ultimate goal is the same as in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215829/how-to-change-the-guest-session-keyboard-layout). I am a Dvorak user, but I want QWERTY, not Dvorak, to be the default keyboard layout in a guest session. If you know a direct answer to that instead of to the question below, that will also be appreciated.

---

I can change the keyboard layout to QWERTY with `setxkbmap -layout us`.

Some googling tells me that if I create a shell script `/etc/guest-session/prefs.sh`, it will be run when the guest session starts.

So I created a `prefs.sh` file containing just that command:

```
setxkbmap -layout us
```

What I expected to happen was to be able to run a guest session and automatically have the keyboard layout set to QWERTY. What actually happened was that when I tried running a guest session, it simply failed and brought me back to the login screen.

I must be misunderstanding something, but I don't know what. Any ideas?

If relevant: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 3):

The way you did it, the command was run prematurely, i.e. before the actual start of the guest-session. Try this instead:

```
echo 'setxkbmap -layout us' >> $HOME/.profile
```

I just rewrote the [tutorial about customizing guest sessions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession). It might help you understand it better.

*Edit:*

This has become more tricky on later Ubuntu versions. These lines in `/etc/guest-session/prefs.sh` work for me on Ubuntu 15.10:

```
echo "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources \"[('xkb', 'se'), ('xkb', 'us')]\"" >> $HOME/.profile
echo "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 1" >> $HOME/.profile
```

The `('xkb', 'se')` value is my system default (a Swedish keyboard layout). So basically I set a list with my system default and the keyboard layout I want to use in the guest sessions - English (US). Then I tell the system to make the second value in the list the current keyboard layout. 0 (zero) would have been the first value.

Comment: Hmm this did not work for me. I can open a guest session but Dvorak is still the keyboard layout.

Comment: @zorkerz: Not for me either. I just edited my answer.

Comment: Your update worked for me (Ubuntu 16.04 beta).

Comment: @zorkerz: Great. :)